# How to take $\int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 t + b^2 \cos^2 t}\ dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Calculate $\int_{\lambda} f \ ds$ where $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ is
>   given by $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and
>   $\lambda:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R^2}$ is the path $\lambda(t) = (a\cos t,
>  b\sin t)$ which describes an ellipsis

Here's what I did:

$$\int_{\lambda} f \ ds = \int \sqrt{(a\cos t)^2 + (b\sin t)^2}|\lambda'(t)| \ dt= \int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 t  + b^2 \cos^2 t}\ dt$$

I'm stuck here. If I multiply the insides of the square roots I get an even worse integral. Does someone know a method?

Comment: First instinct,  set b^2=a^2+c

Comment: Or use polar coordinates?

Comment: This is more than likely leading to ellptic integrals of the first and second kinds with awful arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the problem of the antiderivative $$I=\int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 (t) + b^2\sin^2 (t)}\,\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 (t)  + b^2 \cos^2 (t)}\ dt$$consider first $$A=(a^2\cos^2 (t) + b^2\sin^2 (t))\,(a^2\sin^2 (t)  + b^2 \cos^2 (t))$$ and replace $\cos^2(t)$ by $(1-\sin^2(t))$ and finish using double angle formulae to end with 
$$A=a^2 b^2+\frac{a^2-b^2}{4}  \sin ^2(2 t)$$ which makes $$I=\int \sqrt{a^2 b^2+\frac{a^2-b^2}{4}  \sin ^2(2 t) }\,dt=\sqrt{a^2b^2}\int\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2-b^2}{4a^2b^2}  \sin ^2(2 t) }\,dt$$  which is  an incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind  in trigonometric form (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)).

So, finally, $$I=\frac{\sqrt{a^2b^2} }2 E\left(2 t\left|-\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2}{4 a^2 b^2}\right.\right)$$ which is much simpler than I was expecting in my comment.

$$J=\int_0^c \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 (t) + b^2\sin^2 (t)}\,\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 (t)  + b^2 \cos^2 (t)}\ dt=\frac{\sqrt{a^2b^2} }2 E\left(2 c\left|-\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2}{4 a^2 b^2}\right.\right)$$

Comment: Presumably $a, b >0$, so that $\sqrt{a^2b^2} = ab$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog. As you wrote, *presumably*.